# Excel equivalent of "Get link to this cell"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

In Google sheets *Right click* > *"Get link to this cell"* creates a url that when clicked 1) opens the relevant google sheet and 2) puts the cursor on that cell. **Note that the link should work outside Excel e.g. in an email**

As an example (this link does **not** work, it is an example):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_5Ye7RWcGprxFrWUTupWmGDmZKUyJCasdfasf6uVYZf2jQmiw/edit#gid=0&range=E8

Does the equivalent feature exist in **Excel** either for the desktop version or the online version?

Answer (score 3):

Both Excel Online and Excel Desktop have this capability but each starts from the cell destined to hold the hyperlink.

In Excel Online, start from the cell that you want to hold the hyperlink and right-click then choose Hyperlink.

[image]

Build the hyperlink from the options available.

In Excel Desktop, start from the cell that you want to hold the hyperlink and right-click then choose Link.

[image]

Build the hyperlink from the options available.

Comment: It is possible to get the link text directly, so that it can e.g. to put the link in email or other application? i.e. get the 'https://....'

Answer (score 1):

To give a hyperlink, first define a name to the cell you want to point to.

Then, select the cell you want to give hyperlink to, and select Link to => Place in this document => your defined name => Ok.

Next time you click on this hyperlink, you'll be redirected to the defined sheet's cell directly.

[I just created a sample for this answer, try it once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUbm6.jpg)

Comment: Is is possible to get the link to use in applications outside Excel e.g. in an email?

Answer (score 1):

In Office 365, you can now select "Copy Link To Range" from the context menu in both the app and the online version. The document needs to be saved on Sharepoint / Onedrive for that to work.